# How to write a custom map canvas item by subclassing QObject and QgsMapCanvasItem?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I'm writing a QGIS python plugin where I place some QgsVertexMarkers on the canvas like this:

```
marker = QgsVertexMarker(self.canvas)
marker.setCenter(QgsPoint(point[0],point[1]))
```

Now i would like being able to drag and drop them. I tried implementing a class that inherits QObject and QgsMapCanvasItem so I can use mouse events.

```
class myVertexMarker(QObject,QgsMapCanvasItem):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        QgsMapCanvasItem.__init__(self,canvas)
        ...

    def setCenter(self,point):
        self.center = point
        pt = QPointF(self.toCanvasCoordinates(self.center))
        self.setPos(pt)

    def some setters, mouse events, paint and so on...
```

Now when I create an object of that class and call setCenter I get this error message:

```
pt = QPointF(self.toCanvasCoordinates(self.center)) #TypeError: could not convert
'myVertexMarker' to 'QgsMapCanvasItem'
```

What am I doing wrong?